# Adding content before the loop in category pages

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am creating a plugin and I want to show all sub category list in the top of every category page. I had created a function and call "`wp_list_categories`" in that function. The problem is when I call that via

```
add_filter('the_content', 'myfunction');
```

List of all sub category is return successfully. Before every post and i just want to show it in top before first post.

And when call same function via

```
add_filter('wp_list_categories', 'myfunction');
```

Nothing return and show blank page

Comment: are you sure to do that with a plugin ? it's "presentation-side" so I recommand you to make this in the theme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`loop_start` should be a good option. `loop_start` executes before the loop displays the first post

### EXAMPLE:

```
add_action( 'loop_start', function ( $q )
{
    if (    $q->is_main_query() // Do this only for the main query
         && $q->is_category() // Only target category pages
    ) {

        // Add your code here 

    }
});
```

Comment: awesome bro sve my life i was searching it from 2 days. i am new wordpress user.

Thank you Very very Much can you give a like to my question? i m unable to give you like\

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. Enjoy :-)

Comment: This should also answer your other question which I have indicated as a duplicate to this one ;-)